# Load a CBitmap dynamically

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

I have a Bitmap image that i want to load dynamically.  But I am unable to load it.

```
CBitmap bmp;

bmp.LoadBitmap("c:\\aeimg");
```

it does not seem to be working.
Can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also try something like this:

```
CImage image;
image.Load(_T("C:\\image.png"));
CBitmap bitmap;
bitmap.Attach(image.Detach());
```

Answer (score 3):

According to CBitmap documentation: `LoadBitmap()` function takes resource identifier of the bitmap or resource id of the bitmap.

You can't specify the path of the bitmap file.

E.g.

```
MyProject.rc
------------
MYBMP      BITMAP  "res\myimage.bmp"
```

and make sure that resource.h does not have any entry of MYBMP otherwise during preprocessing its replaced by id and ultimately `LoadBitmap()` will fail since application can't locate the resource as `FindResource()` fails.

Now do this :

```
CBitmap bmp;
bmp.LoadBitmap(L"MYBMP");
```

It will definitely load the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

To load a bitmap from a file, you want to use `LoadImage` with the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag.

Answer (score 1):

`CBitmap` doesn't support directly reading from a .bmp file. You can instead make use of `CImage` class as suggested in other answers. You'll need to include `atlimage.h` in your code to make `CImage` work:

```
#include <atlimage.h>
:
CImage img;
img.Load (_T("C:\\image.bmp"));
CBitmap bitmap;
bitmap.Attach(img.Detach());
```

Another way is to load the image using `LoadImage` Win32 API and then attaching `CBitmap` to that:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,"c:\\image.bmp", 
                                      IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
if (hBitmap != NULL) 
   bitmap.Attach(hBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

CImage doesn't work with png last time I tried / checked. Have a look at CxImage - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cximage.aspx .

Comment: It supports bmp, jpg, gif and png. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06f3fhw(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I had to look it up, and you're correct as far as loading from a file goes. My recollection came from it being impossible to load pngs from the resources, as CImage::LoadFromResource() uses ::LoadImage() while Load() uses GDI+.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as you forgetting to escape the backslash.
Instead of

```
bmp.LoadBitmap("c:\aeimg");
```

use

```
bmp.LoadBitmap("c:\\aeimg");
```

Otherwise you're passing an invalid path to the LoadBitmap method.

Answer (score 0):

```
CString filename;
TCHAR szFilter[] = _T("Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|PNG (*.png)|*.png||");

CFileDialog selDlg(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | OFN_EXTENSIONDIFFERENT, szFilter, this);


if (selDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    filename = selDlg.GetPathName();

    CImage image;

    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,filename, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);


    if (hBitmap)
    {
    // Delete the current bitmap
    if (m_bmpBitmap.DeleteObject())
        m_bmpBitmap.Detach();   // If there was a bitmap, detach it

    // Attach the currently loaded bitmap to the bitmap object
    m_bmpBitmap.Attach(hBitmap);

    Invalidate();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the solutions mentioned to date, with a member variable of CBitmap I kept getting memory leaking every time I loaded the CImage onto the CBitmap. I solved this with the following code:

```
CString _fileName(/*Path to image*/);
CImage _image;          
HRESULT hr = _image.Load(_fileName);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    if (m_Display.m_bmpImage.DeleteObject())
        m_Display.m_bmpImage.Detach();              
    m_bmpImage.Attach(_image->Detach());
}
```