# CBitmap and CImage interchangeable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'd like to know how something like this can be done

```
CBitmap bmp;  
CImage img;

///

bmp=img;  

//use bmp here
```

In my program I have to use CBitmap at some point but from the start I am only around with CImage.

Comment: This SO question is going the other way, but perhaps it is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091203/load-a-cbitmap-dynamically

Answer (score 6):

Sort of `CImage` is GdiPlus and `CBitmap` is MFC. You can do something like this:

```
CBitmap bmp;  
CImage img;
bmp = CBitmap::FromHandle(img.Detach());
```

**Edit:** Actually `CBitmap` has an attach so might be more efficient to do this:

```
bmp.Attach(img.Detach());
```

Comment: They both wrap HBITMAP at the end of the day. `CImage` is known to have performance issues so may want to implement things differently if that's a concern.